# Can someone correct my understanding of how do-while-loop work

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, do-while, continue

I hope everyone is doing well

I am going to share my understanding of how do-while loop work and i need YOU guys to tell am i,right or not?

Here is the code first:

```
let k= 1

do{
    if(k===9){
        k++;
        continue;
    }
    console.log(k+1);
    k= k+1;
}while(k<15);
```

So what this code does is it takes k=1 and in console.log(k+1) , it prints k = 2.
And then 1 is added to K original value of 1 and it checks whether the condition is true or not.

If its true, then it will move forward to make another loop and check it.

And when k value reaches to 9, the IF condition becomes true and k++ adds 1 to 9 which is equal to 10 and before printing 10, continue statement terminate that loop and start another loop.

This is what i understood on how it works.

Thanks

Comment: You're almost right. `continue` skips the rest of the body and then tests the condition before starting another loop.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar
Got it